# Is there something in front of msg.sender?

Tags: solidity, msg.sender, tx.origin

Tx.origin is an old way of utilizing the handling address behind msg.sender. But let's say I, as a user, am calling a contract and that contract calls a contract. Is there a way for contract B... to specifically only receive calls from only contract A, meaning, is there something in front of msg.sender like tx.origin is behind msg.sender.

Example

Me => Contract A => Contract B

Tx.origin => Msg.sender => ???

Is there a way for contract B to specify, "HEY, ONLY CONTRACT A CAN CALL ME" if I am making a call to contract A from the "me" address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only options you have are `tx.origin` and `msg.sender`. The `tx.origin` is the original EOA (Externally Owned Account) which sent the transaction, while `msg.sender` is the sender of the current (internal) transaction.

From a contract's point of view, `msg.sender` is always the previous contract or EOA in the call chain. So in the chain "EOA => ContractA => ContractB", in the context of ContractB the `msg.sender` is ContractA. In the context of ContractA the `msg.sender` is the EOA.

If the chain is "EOA => ContractA = ContractB => ContractC", there is no way for ContractC to know that there was ContractA in the middle.

Comment: Pardon my pedantry, but there is a way. It involves customisation. One could design a system such that `ContractB` lets `ContractC` know (through calldata) whether it was called by an EOA or by `ContractA`. Or `ContractB` could modify storage, which would be subsequently accessed by `ContractC`.